# Testing Rails Metal/Rack with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rack

Say I have a Metal class named Preview. How do I test it with RSpec?

When I try:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Preview do

  it "should return the posted content" do
    post "/preview", :content => "*title*"
    response.body.should == "*title*"
  end

end
```

I get:

```
undefined method `post' for #<ActiveSupport::TestCase::Subclass_1:0x1058b3098>
```

It seems that RSpec doesn't load up the `:post` method if the test isn't explicitly for a Controller. I've tried specifying `:type => :controller` to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rspec has integration specs that wrap rails integration tests (which go through rack). Just put that spec in `./spec/integration/preview_spec.rb`.

Comment: Bingo. Is this method written up anywhere? Thanks for RSpec and all your work David.

Comment: David, has this changed for Rails 3, or am I just doing it wrong? I have exceptions caught by middleware via a rewritten ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, but my integration tests (even when I put them in `./spec/integration/` just leave the exception uncaught.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to test with rack/test

Comment: Looks good, but I don't want to use another test suite/gem just to test one route. I'm sure you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (rspec-rails 2.2.0 and rails 3) you can achieve that using **Request Specs**:

According to the [readme file](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v2.2.0/README.md):

> Request specs live in spec/requests
>
> [...]
>
> Request specs mix in behavior from Rails' integration tests. See the docs for ActionDispatch::Integration::Runner for more information.