# Testing Response cookie with Rspec v.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I login to my app the server sends me back cookies(credentials and some app's cookie):

```
Response sent 170 bytes of Cookie data:
 Set-Cookie: user_credentials=val; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure

Response sent 554 bytes of Cookie data:
 Set-Cookie: _app_session=otherVal; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
```

...and then redirects to the home page;

Cookies include some flags: e.g. `httpOnly`, `Secure`, etc.

How can I test whether cookies do include those flags with Rspec?

At least where can I find those cookies?

```
it "should generate cookies with proper flags" do    
    params = Factory.attributes_for(:user,
      :username => "uname",
      :password => "upass"
    )
    # login
    post 'create', params

    response.should redirect_to home_url # => pass

    puts "response cookie = #{response.cookies.inspect}" # => {} // no cookies in response, why?
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Controller specs do not generate/invoke *real* http requests, they just set up the controller under test and invoke the requested action on it. No http request is made and no *real* http answer is generated. So you can only test the inner workings of a Rails controller on a more abstract level.

The cookie handling in these specs is rather simple, setting cookies in an action like this:

```
def set_cookies
  cookies[:foo]   = 'bar'
  cookies[:lorem] = {:value => 'ipsum', :expires => 3.days.from_now}

  render :nothing => true
end
```

results in the following values accessible in the spec:

```
it "should set some cookie values" do
  get :set_cookies

  # response.cookies looks like this:
  # {'foo' => 'bar', 'lorem' => 'ipsum'}     

  response.cookies['foo'].should == 'bar'
  response.cookies['lorem'].should == 'ipsum'
end
```

To test the kind of cookie flags that you see in your responses, you would have to use something that does *real* http requests. Maybe you can use the capybara gem for it?

Comment: Hmm.. actually `capybara` is out of my scope of work but still Thank you;

Comment: How are the cookies set anyways? Are you doing that in a controller?

Comment: one of them is set by `Authlogic` gem and another one by `ActionController` i believe

Comment: Seems like there were no other ideas; the bounty is your

Comment: Thanks. I actually looked around a bit more and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2453812/211060 -> it seems that rspec integration tests go through the full stack, including middlewares. You could try to move your spec into spec/integration and do your request with the full path, like `post '/sessions/create'` and then check `response.cookies`... HTH